# How to get count of nan values in one column and non nan values in other columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame with 4 columns

column1   column2  column3 column4
A          2         3       6
B          3         4       Nan
C          5         Nan     6
D          7         Nan    Nan
E          Nan       5       7
F          Nan       7       Nan
G          Nan       Nan     9
H          Nan       Nan     Nan

I want to get count of each such combinations in my data frame.

Expected Output:

Count of rows per combination:

Column1     Column2    Column3
Non Nan     Non Nan     Non Nan

Total rows with above combination :50

Similarly,

Column1    Column2    Column3

Non-Nan     Non-Nan     Nan   - total rows:40

Non-Nan      Nan        Non-Nan - total rows :50

Non-Nan      Nan         Nan    -  total rows :70

Nan         Non-Nan     Non-Nan  - total rows :80

Nan         Non-Nan      Nan       - total rows :60

Nan          Nan        Non-Nan   - total rows :80

Nan          Nan        Nan       - total rows :50

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

Filter columns for count missing/ non missing  values and count values by `sum` :

```
df1 = df.drop('column1', axis=1).isna()
df = df.assign(nan = df1.sum(axis=1), nonnan = (~df1).sum(axis=1))
print (df)
  column1  column2  column3  column4  nan  nonnan
0       A      2.0      3.0      6.0    0       3
1       B      3.0      4.0      NaN    1       2
2       C      5.0      NaN      6.0    1       2
3       D      7.0      NaN      NaN    2       1
4       E      NaN      5.0      7.0    1       2
5       F      NaN      7.0      NaN    2       1
6       G      NaN      NaN      9.0    2       1
7       H      NaN      NaN      NaN    3       0
```

If need count columns:

```
df = df1.agg(['sum', lambda x: (~x).sum()]).rename({'sum':'nan', '<lambda>':'nonnan'})
print (df)
        column2  column3  column4
nan           4        4        4
nonnan        4        4        4
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.drop('column1', axis=1)

df1 = (df1.fillna('nan')
          .where(df1.isna(), 'non nan')
          .groupby(df1.columns.tolist())
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   column2  column3  column4  count
0      nan      nan      nan      1
1      nan      nan  non nan      1
2      nan  non nan      nan      1
3      nan  non nan  non nan      1
4  non nan      nan      nan      1
5  non nan      nan  non nan      1
6  non nan  non nan      nan      1
7  non nan  non nan  non nan      1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get how many no. of rows have got the specified combination.

Comment: @VivekSukhala - Can you add expected ouput to question?

Comment: For example : 23 rows with colum1 nan and column2,column3 non nan.(count of all rows with possible combinations which you got in nan and non nan columns)

Comment: @jezrael- I tried to include expected output.

Comment: @VivekSukhala - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: @jezrael-In the edited answer where you have specified 'non nan' , I have got some integer values instead of 'non nan' in the data frame. Is there any way where it could consider those values as non - nan.

Comment: @VivekSukhala - Not sure if understand. Maybe `nan` are not missing values, but strings, so failed my solution. If test `df1 = df.drop('column1', axis=1).isna()` `print (df1)` there are `True`s for missing values?